# Proxy Socks5 в okHttpClient Android

Tags: android, proxy, mobile-development

Как настроить okHttpClient на работу с socks5, с авторизацией по логин/пароль?

сейчас код выглядит так

```
new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS,InetSocketAddress.createUnresolved(address, port)))
            .build();
```

он работает, когда на сервере нет авторизации.

Нужно это для retrofit, по-этому если есть варианты с другими http-клиентами, то тоже приемлемо, но особенно интересует именно вариант с okHttp,